# Open android app from PUSH notification

Tags: android, push-notification, android-pendingintent, urbanairship.com

Got a little problem that's been bugging me..

I've set up my application to receive PUSH notifications from Urban Airship and that all works fine, but when I tap on a notification in the notifications center, nothing happens.

I want my app to open when a user taps a PUSH notification - what can I do to achieve this?

Any help is as always greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is your application process is alive in background?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a pending Intent to start the activity  and set it in notification using setLatestEventInfo.

Example:

```
  Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
```

More info can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: Where does this code go?  I have the same question as the initial poster but I'm not finding the logical place for this.  If it matters, I'm using Pushwoosh to send my notifications.

Comment: This code is for creating the notification. Do you have any receiver class...? Place it in onreceive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a custom notification builder and use one of your activities as the PendingIntent.

https://docs.urbanairship.com/android-lib/reference/com/urbanairship/push/CustomPushNotificationBuilder.html

Answer (score 1):

Following one of their sample projects (https://github.com/urbanairship/android-samples/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/urbanairship/sample), you can extend the AirshipReceiver class and then override the onReceive method. This did the trick for me:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_OPENED)) {
        Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        launch.setClass(UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext(), MyHome.class);
        launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        launch.putExtra("doWhatever",true);
        UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext().startActivity(launch);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to call pendingIntent before call .setAutoCancel(true);

look at my builder :

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),channel_id).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo).setSound(uri).setVibrate(new long[]{1000,1000,1000,1000,1000})
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true);
```